# Pirámide de números en javascript

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Tengo una pirámide de números, el problema es que tengo que mandarla a imprimir con `document.getElementById()` y ya me salen los números, pero no se acomodan como los necesito, no se como poner los saltos de linea.

Este es el código:

```
    for(var i=0; i<=4; i++){
    for(var x=0; x<=i; x++){
      pira += i;         }
    document.getElementById('piramide').value = pira; }
```

Este es el resultado esperado:

[image: Piramide]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existen varias formas en la que puede lograrlo, tanto con javascript puro como con propiedades css, si lo que deseas es crear la pirámide con una cadenas String debes agregar espacios en blanco antes del primera linea y usar una etiqueta `<pre>`, después ir disminuyendo los espacios en blanco según cada linea. Así.

```
 _ _ _ 1\n
 _ _ 2 _ 2\n
 _ 3 _ 3 _ 3\n
```

Como son 3 lineas aplico a la primera 3 espacios ( _ ) luego disminuyo, El resultado sería:

```
      1
     2 2
    3 3 3
```

Agrego un ejemplo para crear pirámide con javascript y html

```js
function crear_piramide(num_lineas) {
  console.log(num_lineas)
  num_lineas = parseInt(num_lineas)
  var piramide = ""
  piramide = piramideUp(num_lineas+1,0)
  piramide += piramideDown(num_lineas,0,1)
  document.getElementById('piramide').innerText = piramide
}

function piramideUp(num_lineas, inicio){
  let piramide= "" // el string

  for( let i = inicio; i <= num_lineas ; i++){
     //piramide += agregarEspacios(num_lineas,0,i) 
     piramide += agregarNumeros(i-1)
  }
  return piramide
}

function piramideDown(num_lineas, fin, suma){
  let piramide= "" // el string

  for( let i = num_lineas; i > fin ; i--){
     //piramide += agregarEspacios(num_lineas,suma,i) 
     piramide += agregarNumeros(i-1)
  }
  return piramide
}

function agregarNumeros(index){
     let piramide = (index + " ").repeat(index+1)
     return piramide += "\n" // fin de la linea

}

function agregarEspacios(num_lineas,suma, index){
     let piramide = ""
     for( let j = 0; j < (num_lineas+suma) - index; j++){
       piramide += " "  // espacio en blanco antes de cada linea
     }
     return piramide
}
```

```html
<input id="num_lineas" placeholder="Tamaño Piramide" onkeyup ="crear_piramide(this.value)">
<pre id="piramide"></pre>
```

Comment: de hecho ya actualice la foto de como me tiene que quedar la piramide, y para imprimirlo al reves use esto: var inv = piramide.split("").reverse().join(""); pero como le hago para que el 4 no me vuelva a salir y me quede como en la foto?

Comment: y si tambien sabes como la puedo imprimir a partir del cero?

Comment: he actualizado el código , revisa si es lo que deseas, esta comentada la función `agregarEspacios` para que el resultado sea como el de la imagen, si lo des-comentas formara un pirámide centrada.

Answer (score 1):

El problema no es complicado y puede resolverse con un solo bucle con ayuda de la función `repeat`, la cual repite una cadena n veces:

```js
function mostrar () {
    ent=document.getElementById('entero').value;
    cad=ent.repeat(ent*1+1)+'\n';
    for (var i = ent-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      cad+=(i+'').repeat(i+1)+'\n';
      cad=(i+'').repeat(i+1)+'\n'+cad;
    };
    document.getElementById('dmostrar').innerHTML=cad;
}
```

```html
<input id="entero" type="num" onkeyup="mostrar()">
<pre id="dmostrar"></pre>
```

La lógica es empezar por la linea del medio y agregar las lineas de arriba y abajo una a una de adentro hacia afuera.

Para mantener el formato de la piramide se puede usar `<pre>` en lugar de `<div>`.

Espero haber aportado a resolver el problema, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo con la misma lógica con la que empezaste, que entiendo que es correcta, puedes recorrer el total de filas (`altura * 2`), solo que el número que se va a mostrar, cuando sea mayor que la altura de la pirámide, será `altura * 2 - i`, el salto de línea se produce cuando termina cada uno de los segundos ciclos:

```js
const piramide = document.getElementById("piramide");
const altura = 5;// <-- La cantidad de líneas sera el doble

for (let i = 0; i <= altura*2; i++) {

    let cant = (i <= altura) ? i : altura*2 - i; //<-- aumenta o se reduce

    for (let x = 0; x <= cant; x++) {
        piramide.innerHTML += cant;
    }

    piramide.innerHTML += "<br>"; //<-- Termina el segundo ciclo
}
```

```html
<div id="piramide">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function log(){
                var aux="";
                document.write("inicio piramide<br>")
            for (var i = 0; i <=10; i++) {
            
                aux+=i;
                document.write(aux)
                document.write("<br>")
            }
            document.write("fin piramide")

            aux="";
            console.log("inicio piramide")
            console.log("\n")
            for (var i = 0; i <=10; i++) {
            
                aux+=i;
                console.log(aux)
            console.log("\n")
            }
            console.log("\n")
            console.log("fin piramide")

        }
log()
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Ten en cuenta que este _no es un repositorio de código_, por lo tanto pulsa en [edit] y describe brevemente el funcionamiento del código. La respuesta debe ser útil no solo para el OP (autor de la pregunta), sino también para los demás miembros de la comunidad. Lee [answer].