# Piramide de numros repetidos con javascript

Tags: javascript

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación y voy a empezar un curso ahora en breves, total que me han mandado unos ejercicios para ir practicando javascript cosas que ya he visto y estoy atascado en algo desde ayer.

Tengo que hacer una pirámide con números repetidos usando bucles. El resultado que tengo que conseguir es similar a este:
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999

¿Me podríais aconsejar?

Solo consigo hacer está sencillez:

```html
  var i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        document.write("<br>");
        document.write(i);
    }
```

```
}
```

Pero no se m ocurre como hacer el resto.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya vimos que eres principiante, recuerda agregar el código que has intentado o a la otra no habrá piedad con las respuestas.

Comment: Disculpad, lo tendré en cuenta y sorry.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Pirámide de números en javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291304/pir%c3%a1mide-de-n%c3%bameros-en-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a dejar un código de alto nivel, documentado, espero te sirva

```js
// Creas un arreglo de 0 a 10
const arr = Array.from(Array(10), (d, i) => i);

// Pasas por una función cada digito, usa Array.map()
arr.map( d => {
  // Agrega salto de línea
  document.write( '<br>' );
  
  //Ahora, el dígito que llegó ciclalo tantas veces como sea el número que ha llegado
  Array.from( 
    Array( d ), _ => 0 ).map( _ => document.write( d )
  );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola Gonza supongo que si recien empezas habras visto  el for como pones ahi , el while , capaz do while , con esa base pensa que necesitas 2 ciclos , uno que aumente el numero maximo que necesitas imprimir que seria la condicion del primer ciclo y dentro de este otro ciclo donde tome ese numero actual como condicion para imprimirse , y luego de eso vendria el salgo de linea quedaria asi (fijate tambien que  las variables no pueden llevar el mismo nombre)

```js
for(var i = 1 ; i<= 9;i++){


    for (var j  = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        document.write(i);
    }
    
    document.write("<br>");

}
```